# Which distance and generative model?

Tags: classification, density-estimation, nonparametric-density

I am wondering what is a suitable measure to separate the blue, green and red points?
I tried 'cosine' but some of the red gets confused with green. [image]

My goal is to make two generative models; one for blue points and one for green points.

### EDIT

As suggested by the first comment, the same plot is drawn in polar coordinates.  The angle is multiplied by $4$ to be able to see the differences and overlaps better.  [image]

Comment: Consider plotting the polar coordinates of the points: that ought to suggest a useful distance.

Comment: @whuber  Please look at  the new plot. It seems a combination of cosine and something based on Euclidean distance. Also a translation is needed so cosine can be useful. I still cannot figure out exactly what method+distance to use.